# timed display (CSS only) - can we pass duration as part of HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS classes, and HTML code that implement a timed display:

```css
.timedSuccessBox {
  color: white;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  -moz-animation: inAndOut 5s ease-in forwards;
  -webkit-animation: inAndOut 5s ease-in forwards;
  animation: inAndOut 5s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes inAndOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='timedSuccessBox'>That worked!</div>
```

Is it possible to continue only using CSS (no JS) and pass the duration of animation, currently hard coded to 5?

Ideally what I want is, if the invoking HTML code passes a duration, that will be used, else fallback to 5s.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override a custom property which is set to `5s` by default

```css
:root {
  --duration: 5s;
}

.timedSuccessBox {
  color: white;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  -moz-animation: inAndOut var(--duration) ease-in forwards;
  -webkit-animation: inAndOut var(--duration) ease-in forwards;
  animation: inAndOut var(--duration) ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes inAndOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='timedSuccessBox' style='--duration: 10s'>That worked!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this just a little bit better than the simpler style override approach below because it uses a variable abstraction. Out of curiosity, is there any way we can do this dynamically without mixing a css class and inline style together? From a support perspective, looks like all major browsers can deal with variables https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: you could define another class in the CSS setting only a different duration and use both the classes on the element but you lose the capability to set the value on the markup

Comment: Thanks yes, I meant dynamically changing in HTML without having to define classes for each duration (and avoiding mixing inline styles and classes). Mostly curious. Your solution works and may be the best option

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use that in html:

```
<div class='timedSuccessBox' style='animation-duration: 10s!important'>That worked!</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `!important` in a style attribute to override the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks sonic! I think both answers are quite similar at its "root"

Comment: yeah of course :) `:root` way is more elegant.
Its true that you don't need `!important` but I wanted to make it important :D look at the fame hehe